# Loading images in the exported .jar file

Tags: java, image

So I started making this Java game and everything worked fine, except when I tried to export it as a runnable jar. It shows me a blank screen when I try to execute it. I found out that it has to do with the way I'm accessing the images so I tried to change the code according to what i read on here but it's still not working :[

I'm currently accessing the images through:

```
Image image;
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/imageName"));
```

Maybe you guys can help me, would be great!

This is my package tree:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to include your resources inside your exported jar, they need to reside within the `src` folder (otherwise, it'll look for them in the current directory where the jar is run which is susceptible to change and would need to be supplied separately, which doesn't sound like what you want).

Meaning something like:

```
- src
  + com.liakos.SpaceShooter
  - res
    - 1.png
    - 2.png
```

And so on.

Then you can access it through the `getResource` API, i.e.:

```
Image image;
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/1.png"));
```

Comment: Actually I needed to put a slash in front of res, but now it works! Thank you very much, I almost thought I will never solve this.