# Java Image Loading from .jar File

Tags: java, jar, image-loading

I'm trying to load an image from a folder named Custom that the user places images into. Here is the method I used to load images:

```
public BufferedImage getCustImg(String path){
    BufferedImage img = null;
    String s = get.getProgramPath();
    path = path.trim();
    String s2 = s + "\\Custom\\" + path + ".png";

    try{
        img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(s2));//gets image from file path
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return img;
}
```

Here is the program path method

```
public String getProgramPath(){
    File f = new File("./Resources/Sprtes/blank.png");
    String s = f.getAbsolutePath();
    String[] stringArr = s.split("Resources");
    String s2 = stringArr[0];
    s2 = s2.substring(0, s2.length() - 3);
    return s2;
}
```

When I run the code everything works fine but the issue appears when I try to run the program as a .jar file. When I run it using a .jar file, the image doesn't load. This is where the custom folder is in relation to the .jar file:

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R48yS.png)

How should I change the method to make sure that this works?

Comment: Please read java doc for `Class.getResource()`.

Comment: I think this post might answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167205/loading-images-in-the-exported-jar-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the problem thanks to Luke Lee and Olithegoalie,

`img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(s2));` Doesn't work if the path goes outside the jar so I had to change it to

```
public BufferedImage getCustImg(String path){
    BufferedImage img = null;
    String s = get.getProgramPath();
    path = path.trim();
    String s2 = s + "\\Custom\\" + path + ".png";
    try{
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(s2));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return img;
}
```